# I am trying to start npm but it's showing error as please try to re-compling

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run the node application but when i starts running npm using npm start it's showing error as node_module_version 64: please try re-compling or re-installing.

[image: The error img is sttached below]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command: npm rebuild ?

What's the version of your node BTW?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do

1. delete folder "node_modules"
2. npm i -g npm@latest
3. npm i bcrypt@latest
4. npm i